# Retraining time series (Keras) with just the newly arrived data (not fresh training from the scratch)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series

**Introduction:** I have lots of time-series models that I train with Keras weekly.

**Problem:** Training all of these models are getting harder and harder since they require more time and resources in AWS and I am looking for ways of avoiding training from scratch.

**What I know:** I can save models as .h5 and resume training for the newly arrived time-series data.

**What I don't know:** Is it safe to do this or not? I am afraid of hidden dangers on model integrity if I just resume the model training and not start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you train "only" with the new data, you will quickly throw away all your model's previous knowledge. It will learn the new data and forget the old data, possibly overfitting a lot too. Don't do this.

If, on the other hand, you resume from the last point, adding the new data **and also keeping the old data**, there is a possibility that your model is already too biased to the old data and doesn't learn the new data as well as it could (this depends on a lot of factors though, such as how different the new data is, and the proportion of the new data versus the old data)

So, for the second case, it's actually hard to answer, and you might try a few times to see if starting from scratch will be better than resuming. In any case, do not remove the old data from the training set (unless you think that data is now irrelevant for your project).